# C# HttpResponseMessage/Angularjs - to download as Excel doesnt preserve data always

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

I am able to download with HttpResponseMessage and setting all header params and such as shown here in the code extract below:

```
downloadHttpResp.Content = new ByteArrayContent(dwlMemStream.ToArray());
//*******************************************************************************
downloadHttpResp.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
downloadHttpResp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);    
downloadHttpResp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
downloadHttpResp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
```

Issue is with one of the columns - which is ***just a text column*** (but the download and open treats it like a date column). For e.g. I have multiple row-column value occurrences as **11 - 05**, when the download is saved or opened in Excel, it converts to **Nov 05** (like as if its a date). How do I get around this? Is there any other way to overcome, or if some header option/setting that I can set will preserve the data as is and no conversion to be done on the receiving end?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of the file being downloaded. This looks like a problem with Excel reading the file. If for example it is a CSV file excel has no idea what those values are suppose to be and will make a guess. That puts this outside of your control. If how ever the file being downloaded is an actual excel file then you need to make sure that the value type is properly configure when it was originally saved/generated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add = before the occurrences and your occurrence in double quotes like  ="11-05"

Comment: I am getting by right now putting double quotes around all the values in that particular column. But it is not a long term solution

Comment: This is hack for work around this, other way is to change format the columns as Text and save the file to .xls

Comment: I am as such creating a stringbuilder - (with table, tr, td) to - stream - httpResponseMessage so everything is already a string in that sense.

Comment: @user428602 based on your comments this appears to be a flat file, which limits what you can configure in terms of how other applications can interpret your data.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with Excel reading the file. If for example it is a CSV or flat file, excel has no idea what those values are suppose to be and will make a guess.

That puts this outside of your control unless you modify your output to avoid conflicts with the Excel application

If however the file being downloaded is an actual excel file then you need to make sure that the value type is properly configure when it was originally saved/generated.

Comment: Its not the question of Excel file or not. I have a datareader which is the result of an Stored procedure call in my webApi, which I am writing to a html table i.e. table - tr-td which gets written to a stream as a byte array and download as Excel. So dont get what you are saying...

Comment: @user428602 it is still a flat file with just text. Text files have no formatting so the application interpreting the content wont know how to format it.